# Getting Exception when calling CreateIfNotExists (Azure blob client)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am having problem creating an Azure blob container.

When I call CreateIfNotExists() function I get the following exception :

I have search on internet to see if other folks have the same problem or not. I have found two main reasons for this error.

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Stack Trace :

```
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.Exists(Boolean primaryOnly, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType accessType, BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(BlobRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Customize.AzureSpecific.ProductPhotoStorageService..ctor() in c:\Users\raha\Desktop\Customize\Customize.AzureSpecific\ProductPhotoStorageService.cs:line 28
   at lambda_method(Closure , IArguments )
   at StructureMap.Construction.BuilderCompiler.FuncCompiler`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateBuilder>b__0(IArguments args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\767273992e840853\src\StructureMap\Construction\BuilderCompiler.cs:line
```

1. Valid name for blob container
2. The port 1000 is already in use.

None of the above is true, because i tried very simple names and also when I open Storage Emulator I can see that the blob is running on port 1000

Do you guys have any ideas that why this is happening ? any help is appreciated.

Update:

Thank you guys yes you were all correct, the problem was the Storage Emulator version. After installing the preview everything is working as it should.

Comment: Please check the version of storage client library you're using and the SDK version.

Comment: I'd also suggest pointing the same code at a hosted storage account to ensure its not an issue with the local storage emulator.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Storage Client Library, I try to update it every time a new version is available on Nuget so that is probably my problem. As Serdar Ozler mentioned I will probably have to get the Azure Storage Emulator preview release. Once I get home I will try that and keep you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Azure Storage Client Library 3.0, please make sure you have the latest preview release of the Azure Storage Emulator, which can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/01/27/windows-azure-storage-emulator-2-2-1-preview-release-with-support-for-2013-08-15-version.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The valid name for blob container should be in lower case letters